# Compare Row Count & Count in a dataset

Tags: c#, .net, linq

```
DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
DataTable odt = new DataTable();

odt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FILE_ID", typeof(string)));
odt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
oDs.Tables.Add(odt);
oDs.AcceptChanges();

for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[0].NewRow();
oDr["FILE_ID"] = "a";
oDr["ID"] = "b";
oDs.Tables[0].Rows.Add(oDr);
}
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
DataRow oDr = oDs.Tables[0].NewRow();
oDr["FILE_ID"] = "c";
oDr["ID"] = "d";
oDs.Tables[0].Rows.Add(oDr);
}
 oDs.AcceptChanges();
```

How do I compare between the row count & distinct row count for a column "FILE_ID" using linq in an "if statement"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
var allCount = (from row in odt.AsEnumerable() select row).Count(); //Count all rows

var specificCount = (from row in odt.AsEnumerable() select row.Field<string>("FILE_ID")).Distinct().Count();
```